# I want to store credential.access token in a variable, I tried the following but didn't succeed

Tags: javascript, function, store, access-token

```
var Token; 
componentDidMount() {
  auth0.webAuth.authorize({
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    audience: 'https://MyDomain/userinfo' 
   })
   .then(credentials => 
      console.log(credentials.accessToken))
      this.key=credentials.accessToken;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var Token; 
componentDidMount() {
  auth0.webAuth.authorize({
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    audience: 'https://MyDomain/userinfo' 
   })
   .then(credentials => {
      console.log(credentials.accessToken);
      this.key=credentials.accessToken });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you :) Solved

Answer (score 0):

From ComponentDidMount it looks like this is react.

It looks like you are not doing `this.key=credentials.accessToken` inside the callback, but outside. This means credentials.accessToken will be undefined when you try to set this.key=credentials.accessToken;